# Access to a PHP array element from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I am trying to set some fields of a form with the values of an array.

I have an array like this:

```
Array
    {
        'elementID1' => Array
                           {
                               'id1' => 'some value',
                               'id2' => 'some value',
                               'id3' => 'some value',
                               ...
                           }
        'elementID2' => Array
                           {
                               'id1' => 'some value',
                               'id2' => 'some value',
                               'id3' => 'some value',
                               ...
                           }
        ...
    }
```

The array is filled with the response of a webservice to whom I sent some parameters with a form. Once I filled the array, I draw a table and iterate over the array.

```
<table width = "100%" border = "1">
    <tr>
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
        <th>Header 3</th>
        <th>View details</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($array as $id => $detail)
        {       
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    if(array_key_exists('id1', $detail))
                        echo $detail['id1'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    if(array_key_exists('id2', $detail))
                        echo $detail['id2'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    if(array_key_exists('id3', $detail))
                        echo $detail['id3'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href = \"javascript:equisYe('" . $id . "')\">View more</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Now, here comes the problem, as you can see there is a fourth column called View details, this column is filled with a hyperlink that calls a javascript function with the elementID value of the specific row as parameter.

A little more below I have the script:

```
<script>
    function equisYe(id)
    {
        var equis = "<?php echo $array['" + id + "']['IncidentID']; ?>";
        alert(equis);
    }
</script>
```

When I click on the hyperlink doen't happen anything, I think the problem has something to do with the special characters inside the quote punctuations. In my browser, when I inspect one of the hyperlinks, it shows the following message inside de scripts tags:

```
function equisYe(id)
{
    var equis = "<br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  + id +  in <b>
";
    alert(equis);
}
```

That means, for some reason, the strings aren't concatenating, and if I delete a 'p' from php tag in the equis var like this:

```
var equis = "<?ph echo $array['" + id + "']['IncidentID']; ?>";
```

Then the alert shows this:

```
"<?ph echo $array['10']['IncidentID']; ?>"
```

So, it works when it doesn't have the php tags.

Comment: after your page loads, you could iterate over your table in javascript and update the  html links with the values you need.

Comment: either preload the array into json encode or just simply use an xmlhttprequest

Comment: @Ghost, equisye method is not like the one I write above (It will not just pop up an alert), it will set the values of some form fields.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but not explaining it at all (or even politely).  The PHP stuff runs before your Javascript stuff does.  You'll never get this to work this way, unfortunately.  If it was the other way around, it might work, but this isn't going to work the way you have it.

The only way to have something like this working is to have the ID value chosen in advance and have PHP set something in Javascript.  Javascript can never set a PHP value simply by virtue of PHP being run **prior** to the page being served and Javascript being run **after** the page is served.

Answer (score 0):

dude... javascript executes on client(browser) and php on server; you CANNOT do that

Comment: Really? Even though the array is created before the execution of the javascript function?

Comment: You can dump the array as a js variable use json_encode then you access it from javascript

Answer (score 0):

try to use `<? ?>` instead of `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is correct in that you can't simply call PHP functions from Javascript without performing some kind of HTTP request.

Since you already have the "IncidentID" in php while you're generating the page, you can simply write it to the page.

instead of

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href = \"javascript:equisYe('" . $id . "')\">View more</a>";
echo "</td>";
```

do

```
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href = \"javascript:alert('" . $detail['IncidentID'] . "')\">View more</a>";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Yeah, but it would only bring me a single value and I need all the array, that's why I try to send the id of an element of the array to access all the elements inside that element (like IncidentID, Status, etc.).

Comment: Yup, either reproduce your php array in javascript, or do HTTP requests to get the values from the server then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute to pass the $id to js, always using the DOM.

Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Then use a click event in "view details" to get the data from element and trigger the function, this way you will be abble to work with it